# how to use git2go on windows 11 with libgit2

Tags: libgit2

Could someone explain to me on how to use `git2go` in my Go project ?

I already sucesfully downloaded repository of [libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2) and compiled it on Windows. It is compiled to `\Release\git2.dll`, `\Release\git2.exp` and `\Release\git2.lib`. How `git2go` should find it ? Do I need to copy `.h` files also ?

I created a new Go project in VSCode and run `go get github.com/libgit2/git2go/v34`. It is finished successfully without any error.

I created a `main.go` file where I import `github.com/libgit2/git2go/v34` package and try to use it.

The errors are:

```golang
Build Error: go build -o C:\Projects\go-test-01\__debug_bin.exe -gcflags all=-N -l .
# github.com/libgit2/git2go/v34
C:\Users\user01\go\pkg\mod\github.com\libgit2\git2go\v34@v34.0.0\http.go:18:54: undefined: RegisteredSmartTransport
C:\Users\user01\go\pkg\mod\github.com\libgit2\git2go\v34@v34.0.0\http.go:39:43: undefined: Remote
C:\Users\user01\go\pkg\mod\github.com\libgit2\git2go\v34@v34.0.0\http.go:39:62: undefined: Transport
C:\Users\user01\go\pkg\mod\github.com\libgit2\git2go\v34@v34.0.0\http.go:39:74: undefined: SmartSubtransport
C:\Users\user01\go\pkg\mod\github.com\libgit2\git2go\v34@v34.0.0\http.go:70:13: undefined: Transport
C:\Users\user01\go\pkg\mod\github.com\libgit2\git2go\v34@v34.0.0\http.go:74:59: undefined: SmartServiceAction
C:\Users\user01\go\pkg\mod\github.com\libgit2\git2go\v34@v34.0.0\delta_string.go:28:9: undefined: Delta
C:\Users\user01\go\pkg\mod\github.com\libgit2\git2go\v34@v34.0.0\difflinetype_string.go:36:9: undefined: DiffLineType
C:\Users\user01\go\pkg\mod\github.com\libgit2\git2go\v34@v34.0.0\errorclass_string.go:52:9: undefined: ErrorClass
C:\Users\user01\go\pkg\mod\github.com\libgit2\git2go\v34@v34.0.0\errorcode_string.go:55:9: undefined: ErrorCode
C:\Users\user01\go\pkg\mod\github.com\libgit2\git2go\v34@v34.0.0\http.go:74:59: too many errors (exit status 1)
```

according to I need to:

```
This project wraps the functionality provided by libgit2. If you're using a versioned branch, install it 
to your system via your system's package manager, and then install git2go.
```

**I don't understand how I could install libgit2 so git2go will find it (on Windows)** If this is what errors above mean

Thanks for your help !